# PyDev Interactive Console for Eclipse , import <modulename> throws ImportError

Tags: python-2.7, pydev, eclipse-luna

I have created a PythonProject in `Eclipse Luna`. I am trying to run python module via `PyDev Interactive Console`, but a simple `import <ModuleName>` does not work it throws the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\Users\SAMA0714\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.0.0.201504132356\pysrc\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
>     module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
>
> ImportError: No module named first

I have changed the working directory of console via

```
import os
os.chdir(<to_the_src_folder_of_my_project_where_I_put_my_python_modules)
```

but still I face the same error. Generally when I do the `import statement`, If I type the first character of my module name I use to get the available modules with the name, but I do not see the names. 
I've look into various stackoverflow question, but none were appropriate. any help is appreciated. 
I have also tried `running the console for the present editor option` in the Eclipse Console Options, but in vain.
But it works fine on `Eclipse Kepler version.`

**UPDATE**
**PyDev Interactive Console**

[image]

**Project Explorer**

[image]

This is my on job system which is a 64-bit machine. I have a 32-bit machine at home on which python interactive console works smooth.
On my home machine, I have had python on local drive `c`. On my job system I had installed it in documents folder which I now moved to `C`, but still the error persists.

Comment: Can you give more details on the structure/name of module (a screenshot of your pydev package explorer would be nice to help diagnose it -- as well as the actual interactive session with the error).

Comment: @FabioZadrozny I have added screenshots of the console error and project explorer as suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The locations in which Python looks for modules are in `sys.path` which can also be modified. What output do you get when printing it?

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

You could try adding your path to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(<full_path_to_the_src_directory)
```

Comment: Thanks your solutions has solved the problem. To do this every single time is painfully,whenever I create a new project, how to dynamically add paths to sys, When I create a new project. 
Whenever I start a new session the changes made to the path are lost. I tried `sys.path[6] = sys.path[6] + '"\\src\\"` where src is my module location and `sys.path[6]` is my project top folder

Comment: Yeah, something is definitely going on there. What do you get when doing `print sys.path`? The first item in my list is `''` which is what makes import from the current directory to work. If I remove that item it no longer does.

Comment: The Value of `sys.path` upon startup is this:
['C:\\Users\\SAMA0714\\Documents\\Eclipse_kepler\\plugins\\org.python.pydev_4.0.0.201504132356\\pysrc', 'C:\\Python2764', 'C:\\Python2764\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python2764\\lib', 'C:\\Python2764\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python2764\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\SAMA0714\\workspace_kepler\\FirstPythonProject', 'C:\\Python2764\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python2764\\lib\\plat-win']

Comment: You can probably set the initial `sys.path` somewhere in the project settings in Eclipse. The default behavior should be including current path there, so Eclipse is probably modifying it somehow.